# How to active my js code in Joomla 3?

Tags: joomla

I want to active js code when click to button in joomla.. when I run this code in xampp it work, but when added it in joomla code it not work. I try code in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CGgJ.jpg) in joomla & try include js file but it also not work. Can anyone help me??

My Code:

```
    //Javascript code
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('form_send_email');

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    /*CSS code*/
    #form_details button {background-color: #4CAF50;color: white;padding: 14px 20px;margin: 8px 0;border: none;cursor: pointer;width: 100%;}
    #form_details button:hover {opacity: 0.8;}
    #form_send_email .imgcontainer {// text-align: left;margin: 24px 0 12px 0;position: relative;}
    #form_send_email .container {padding: 16px;}
    #form_send_email.modal { display: none; position: fixed; z-index: 1;left: 0;top: 0;width: 100%;height: 100%;overflow: auto;background-color: rgb(0,0,0); background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);padding-top: 60px;}
    #form_send_email .modal-content {background-color: #fefefe; margin: 5% auto 15% auto; border: 1px solid #888; border-radius: 5px; -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); width: 80%;}
    #form_send_email .close {position: absolute; right: 25px; top: 0; color: #000; font-size: 35px; font-weight: bold; }
    #form_send_email .close:hover,#form_send_email .close:focus {color: red; cursor: pointer;}
    #form_send_email.animate {-webkit-animation: animatezoom 0.6s;animation: animatezoom 0.6s}
    @-webkit-keyframes animatezoom {
        from {-webkit-transform: scale(0)} 
        to {-webkit-transform: scale(1)}
    }    
    @keyframes animatezoom {
        from {transform: scale(0)} 
        to {transform: scale(1)}
    }
    <div id="form_details"> 
    <button class="btn" onclick="document.getElementById('form_send_email').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;">Login</button>
    </div>

    <div id="form_send_email" class="modal animate">
      <div class="modal-content ">
        <div class="imgcontainer">
          <span class="close" title="Close Modal" onclick="document.getElementById('form_send_email').style.display='none'">&times;</span>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
        <p>content</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error on js console?

Comment: There is no error in js console. It just like skipping my js code, or maybe my function not wrote in correct way ! (but it work without joomla!!)